# Having issues with Android app opening a web page

Tags: android

I am having a bit of an issue with my Android app. Everything else is working except when I go to try the list that is supposed to take me to a website, the emulator stops working.

```js
package net.androidbootcamp.cityguide;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  String[] attraction={"Alcatraz Island", "Ferry Marketplace", "Golden Gate Bridge", "Cable Car Trolley", "Fisherman's Wharf"};
  setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_main,R.id.travel, attraction));
 }
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView i, View v, int position, long id){
  switch(position){
  case 0:
   startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://alcatrazcruises.com/")));
   break;
  case 1:
   startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.farrybuildingmarketplace.com")));
   break;
  case 2:
   startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Bridge.class));
   break;
  case 3:
   startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Trolley.class));
   break;
  case 4:
   startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Wharf.class));
   break;
  }
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
  return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
  // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
  // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
  int id = item.getItemId();
  if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
   return true;
  }
  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
}
```

That's the main activity code, and the error I'm getting on the log is

```
02-24 19:14:32.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1038): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-24 19:14:32.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1038): Process: net.androidbootcamp.cityguide, PID: 1038
02-24 19:14:32.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1038): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://www.farrybuildingmarketplace.com }
02-24 19:14:32.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1765)
02-24 19:14:32.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1485)
02-24 19:14:32.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3736)
02-24 19:14:32.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3697)
02-24 19:14:32.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4007)
02-24 19:14:32.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3975)
02-24 19:14:32.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at net.androidbootcamp.cityguide.MainActivity.onListItemClick(MainActivity.java:28)
02-24 19:14:32.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:319)
02-24 19:14:32.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:300)
02-24 19:14:32.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1143)
02-24 19:14:32.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3044)
02-24 19:14:32.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3833)
02-24 19:14:32.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
02-24 19:14:32.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-24 19:14:32.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-24 19:14:32.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
02-24 19:14:32.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-24 19:14:32.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-24 19:14:32.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
02-24 19:14:32.406: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

I'm not 100% sure how I'm supposed to add the error log. I hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

Your emulator does not have installed web browser and when you try to open it your application crashes.

Add exception handler when you start web browser to avoid crashes.

```
try {
           startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://website.com/")));
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "App not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
    }
```

Comment: Your advice is good if i dont want the app to crash the thing is i need it to load so i gusse the new question is how do i add web browsers to my emulator?